# afraid of snatching vs afraid of being snatched

Tags: sentence-construction, difference

> I think you are afraid of snatching.
> I think you are afraid of being snatched.

Which sentence is looking more accurate?

Comment: I don't understand what ***to snatch*** means here. With a different verb, such as ***to eat***, there's a clear-cut difference. The gerund-based form *He is afraid of **eating*** has the implied subject "he" (perhaps he doesn't want to eat because he fears the food is poisonous). The passive form *He is afraid of **being eaten*** is completely different - he fears that some (unspecified) person / creature might eat **him*** (where "him / he" is syntactically the *object*, not *subject*)..

Answer (score 1):

There is possibly an echo of

- You are possibly worried about burglary.
- You are possibly worried about being burgled.

where the two variants are virtually interchangeable (and acceptable).

However, there are few cases where both variants are interchangeable.

- You are possibly worried about rape / being raped. (both variants idiomatic ... sadly)
- You are possibly worried about being burgled. (far more likely version)
- You are possibly worried about being attacked. (only normally idiomatic variant available)
- You are possibly worried about arson. (only variant available)
- You are possibly worried about fraud. ('being defrauded' less likely)

Here, unless 'snatch' is slang for 'kidnapping',

- You are possibly worried about your bag being snatched.

is probably what is required. The variant '- You are possibly worried about bag-snatching' is less likely, though quite grammatical, and not unidiomatic in a formal register. It doesn't overlap in meaning completely. And 'You are possibly worried about rape', for instance, can have the non-personal sense 'in your capacity of Police Officer in charge of curtailing Violent Crime'.